# Gwt Production Mode in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, production

Specifically, I wonder how to compile project for production mode in IntelliJ IDEA. So far I have found only dev mode mentions and the official JetBrains guide describes only devmode. Now, when I compile my gwt module in IDEA using "Compile module" from context menu and try to run it in browser calling:

```
localhost:8888/MySampleApplication.html
```

I always get message "Gwt module need(s) to be recompiled".

Comment: Have you tried to do a clean refresh in your browser ? Shift + click on the reload button. I've this issue all the time after a compilation because my client have some js cached around.

Comment: It doesn't help. The matter is I don't have any context menu for Gwt in IDEA now, like I had in Eclipse, where I could choose to compile properly.I only can call "Compile module" now. That's why I think I don't have any thing like "target" directory with js cache at all.

Comment: I'm using GWT inside a grails application, so the GWT part is managed by grails command. I don't know exactly how it works with pure GWT app. Do you have any gwt dir in your source dir 'web-app' ?

Comment: Yes, I do have usual package structure i.e. client and server in my source folder.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. The grails plugin for GWT is creates a gwt dir in my web-app that contains the js files used by the dev mode. It is like a build dir for GWT and I can delete the content to do a clean operation.

Comment: I don't have any folder with js cache inside my project structure, despite calling "make" or "compile module" from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have defined a maven run configuration with the command line:

```
clean gwt:compile -Dgwt.inplace=true
```

Now the compiler writes his output in the source directory ( in our case /src/main/webapp). If I take now the url without the parameter for the codeserver I get the correct results.

I hope this will help!